# Add Class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Html mark-up is somthing like this

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="last">
         <div class="a">
                 <div class="b">
                        <div class="c"></div>
                 </div>
         </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Want to add a extra class in `<div class="last">`,`<div class="a">`,`<div class="b">`, and `<div class="c">`. Using jQuery

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div:last').addClass('yourclass');
```

Answer (score -1):

**[See Demo Here :)](http://jsbin.com/uroca3)**

Last div:

```
$('div.last').addClass('class');
```

Last div of the last div:

```
$('div.last').find('div:last').addClass('class');
```

See more info about:

**[addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)**
**[:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)**